# Array value shows all information of the coreData value rather than just the value

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data

I'm hoping someone can help me understand how to get the value from an array rather than all system information about the array as shown via screen shot below.

[image]

I would instead prefer just "test" to show to prove that CoreData saved and returned the value.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let newItem = Item(context: context)
var textIn = ""
var textOut = ""
var itemArray = [] as Array

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var dataIn: UITextField!
    
    @IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
        
        newItem.title = dataIn.text
        saveItems()
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBAction func showButton(_ sender: Any) {
        
        loadItems()
    }
    
    func saveItems() {
        
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Saved!")
        } catch {
            print("Error saving context \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func loadItems() {
        
        let request : NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
        do {
            itemArray = try context.fetch(request) as [Any]
            for item in itemArray {
                print(item.self)
                textLabel.text = ("Value: \(item.self)")
                    }
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching data from context \(error)")
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than the worst type `[Any]` use the best type `[Item]`

```
var itemArray = [Item]()
```

Then remove the pointless type cast in `loadItems` to be able to use the `title` attribute

```
func loadItems() {
    
    let request : NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
    do {
        itemArray = try context.fetch(request)
        for item in itemArray {
            print(item.title)
            textLabel.text = ("Value:", item.title)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching data from context \(error)")
    }
}
```

Consider that after the loop the label will display always the `title` of the last item in the array.